# Увеличение памяти в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Что делать если уже увеличил в С:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 9.0\bin\ строку до

> -Xmx2048m

перезагрузил, но шторм всё равно показывает в углу максимум 974m

Comment: А если меньше 900 поставить? :)

Answer (score 3):

Help-Edit Custom VM Options...
Если файла не существует, то попросит согласия создать его в пользовательской директории. В открывшемся файле редактируем

```
-Xmx2048m
```

и перезагружаем шторм
у меня сработало
2017.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылка с пояснениями:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/increasing-memory-heap.html

Или зайдите в верхнем меню **help** -> **change memory settings**

И там уже можно изменить вручную количество выделяемой памяти